# how to let interpolation skip a zone in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, contour

I have some data, they are some scatter points, I try to use `scatterinterpolant` function to have a smooth contour, but in my situation, there is a block in the zone, in this block, there should be nothing. but after interpolation, the block is filled with data, what I like is let the interpolation skip or ignore this block.

I have a simple code to show what I try to get,but it doesn't work. I would be grateful if anybody  give me any suggestion?

```
clear all
a=randi(100,[1000,2]);
b=rand(1000,1);
F=scatteredInterpolant(a,b);
[xi,yi]=meshgrid(1:1:100,1:1:100);
vi=zeros(size(xi));
if (xi>50) %& xi<70
id=find(xi>50 );

vi(id)=nan;
else
vi(:,:)=F(xi,yi);
end
figure,scatter(a(:,1),a(:,2),b)
figure,contourf(xi,yi,vi)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *there should be nothing*? Zeros or NaNs in a matrix?

Comment: you can imagine in physics, in the whole zone, looks like there is a stone in a box, the box is full filled air, I would like to say that It is impossible to get any data from the stone. NaNs, I think, is better to describe it.